# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to convert data to an object while trying to click an element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

im trying to click a button on a page after logging in the button is the following HTML

```
<div id="carrierDashboardControls">
      <button class="yms-button-primary" ng-click="refresh()">
         <t>Refresh</t>
      </button>
      <button class="yms-button-primary-alt ng-isolate-scope" ng-csv="fetchData()" lazy-load="true" 
  csv-header="getCsvHeader" filename="carrier-dashboard.csv" field-separator=",">CSV
      </button>
</div>
```

there are 2 buttons in this and i want to click the one with class 
"yms-button-primary-alt ng-isolate-scope"
however i get the follwing error

this button will download a CSV file when clicked but right now i get the error "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to convert data to an object"

im currently using the below code, note the actual url's cannot be shared due to the nature of the business (i navigate to the url twice due to a redirection after login)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os


url = "THE URL"
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'MYPATH/geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.get(url)

user_field = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_email")
pass_field = driver.find_element_by_id("ap_password")
sign_in = driver.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit")
user_field.send_keys(username)
pass_field.send_keys(password)
sign_in.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(100)
driver.get(url)
CSV_BUTTON = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yms-button-primary-alt ng-isolate-scope")
CSV_BUTTON.click()
```

as an added note i would like to manipulate the file that is downloaded afterwards as i would like to have it auto  renamed with current date and time if this is possible ?

FULL STACKTRACE BELOW

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/YMS scrape/venv/YMS Sel#.py", line 26, in <module>
    CSV_BUTTON = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yms-button-primary-alt ng-isolate-scope")
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\YMS scrape\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\YMS scrape\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\YMS scrape\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\YMS scrape\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to convert data to an object
```

Comment: Can you share full stacktrace?

Comment: @AlexeyR. sorry i dont know how to find that ? do you mean the traceback ? im using pycharm if that helps

Comment: Yes, basically it is a call stack showing where the exception has been generated and which calls preceded the failure. Normally it is printed in dev mode but sometims supressed.

Comment: @AlexeyR. i think i added it all in the bottom of my post ? be sure to let me know if im being silly and this is not it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is an dynamic element which becomes visible through [lazy-loading](/questions/tagged/lazy-loading), so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.yms-button-primary-alt.ng-isolate-scope[csv-header='getCsvHeader'][ng-csv^='fetchData']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='yms-button-primary-alt ng-isolate-scope' and @csv-header='getCsvHeader'][contains(., 'CSV')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you, i had to put a sleep command in due to something else obscuring the button for a few seconds but its only 5 seconds